# Good Perfmon Counters for Initial Troubleshooting

Tags: windows, windows-7, perfmon, bottleneck

I increasingly deal with users who complain there "computer is slow" or that "it takes forever to load" on the laptops we provide (fairly standard build of Windows 7 32-bit with Office 2010 and a few other enterprise apps for calendaring and such).  I wanted a more official way to diagnose the problem and find out if it is BS or not, so I want to use the Performance Monitor.

**Outside the standard System Performance counters there by default in the perfmon console**, what do you guys use to tease out troublesome applications? Keep in mind I am very new to this and TechNet articles seem insufficient.